# How do I perform a summation of `n` rows at a time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a data frame

```
     A
0   14
1   59
2   38
3   40
4   99
5   89
6   70
7   64
8   84
9   40
10  30
11  94
12  65
13  29
14  48
15  26
16  80
17  79
18  74
19  69
```

This data frame has 20 columns. I would like to group `n=5` rows at a time and sum them up. So, my output would look like this:

```
     A
0  250
1  347
2  266
3  328
```

`df.rolling_sum` will not help because it does not allow you to vary the stride when summing.

What other ways are there to do this?

Comment: Before blindly downvoting, PLEASE READ: [duplicates can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/) There is nothing wrong with asking a question that was marked duplicate.

Comment: Agreed. Also, this isn't an exact duplicate. It's close enough that I won't undo the dup flag. But yours asked about sum. The other asked about average. Different people will think to search for different things. If your question is phrased in a way that ultimately guides more people to the answer they need, then you have contributed a useful question, even if it is a duplicate.

Comment: I also added my answer to that question 

Comment: @piRSquared And I upvoted! Thanks for the support.

Comment: @piRSquared I say the question is definitely a duplicate as the questions do not really ask how to take the `sum`  or the `mean` but in general how to group (to aggregate) these observations. But I agree duplicates are useful. I might have even closed the other one as a duplicate of this one if it weren't were for Divakar's answer because the phrase "n rows at a time" seems more common. Anyway, I wouldn't read so much into the downvotes as everybody here has their own standards it is not  possible to keep up with all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.set_index(df.index // 5).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Oh, this is new. Didn't know about levels... cool...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your indices are contiguous, you can perform integer division on `df.index`, and then group by index.

For the `df` above, you can do this:

```
df.index // 5
# Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Getting the final answer is just one more step, using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`dfGroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby(df.index // 5).sum()

     A
0  250
1  347
2  266
3  328
```

If you do not have a `RangeIndex`, use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first and then group.

Answer (score 2):

If you can manage an ndarray with the sums as opposed to a Series (you could always construct a Series again anyhow), you could use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).

```
np.add.reduceat(df.A.values, np.arange(0, df.A.size, 5))
```

Which in this case returns

```
array([250, 347, 266, 328])
```